# Mysql query excluding currently displayed item

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL (not using PDO or MySQLi at the moment) query that shows product items. I have decided to use a single PHP page with code snippets based on `get_` and `isset` so if `page.php?id=1` or `page.php?cat=pills` will generate a different looking page.

Along with this when I go into `page.php?id=1` I want related items to show at the bottom which is working with the code I have except it is also showing the currently displayed id which is not the desired effect.

```
Relevant | Tables
-------------------
product  | short description price
category | short category expert
```

My code basically sees the product id currently selected and looks for the short (short form of category) and defines it as a variable.

the next bit of code displays all the products matching the short category.

code

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id='$id'", $con);
if(!$qry)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}

/* Fetching data from the field "category" and article id is transferred to product.php file */
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
$cat=$row['short'];

$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE short='$cat' order by product.id DESC", $con);
if(!$qry)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}

                /* Fetching data from the field "title" */
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
echo "<a href='product.php?id=".$row['id']."'>";

echo "<div class='prod_item2'>";
echo "<h3>".$row['name']."</h3>";
echo "<img src='".$row['image']."' /><br>";
echo "<h2><img style='height:7%;' src='images/rs.png' />".$row['price']."</h2><br>";
echo "</div></a>";

}



}
}
```

I want all the items to show except the one selected currently in product.

you can see the result in `indianskincare.co.in` and click on one of the categories on the left and then a product. everything is perfect except the part where related products shows all the products including the selected product id. how do I modify the query to exclude the current product.id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your sql query you can simply exclude getting the record with the current ID.

something like `$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE short='$cat' AND id!='$id' order by product.id DESC", $con);`

Comment: perfect. knew it was something really simple. i didn't know syntax so tried NOT and == but both didn't work .

Comment: i think mysql support != and <> both ways for NOT